# I changed my /usr permission of ec2 instance to read only . After that not able to perform any command

Tags: read-only, aws

I changed my /usr permission to read only . After that not able to perform any command.

Not event able to execute , "clear" or any other operation , nor able to login as sudo .
sudo command is not found.

/usr/ now has following permission :
`dr--------`

What can I do to get following permission back :
`drwxr-xr-x`

I am unable to perform any operation like :
`vi`
`sudo`
`chmod`
`clear`

Comment: Why did you change it? What were you trying to do?

Comment: i was trying to update my node version , for which it wanted to create a folder in bin , so I tried changing its permission and this happened. Any idea , how can I perform othrer activities and set my /usr/ permission back to previous ones ? :( Now I can't even "cd" inside /usr/ .

Comment: Create an Ubuntu image on a USB drive.  Boot from it.  Then mount your `/` drive and try changing the permissions back.

Comment: @Ray . This I did on an ec2 instance . How can i do that what you have suggested ?

Comment: If it’s an EC2 instance, you’re out of luck. Terminate and recreate 

Comment: Well, `chmod` is just a program that is from the package `coreutils`.  I suppose another way is to extract the minimum number of programs you need to fix your problem over to your EC2 instance.  You can give that a try.  But honestly, it's probably easier to recreate your EC2 instance.

Comment: @matigo are you sure ? No solution is possible ?

Comment: @Ray , I didn't understand : extract the minimum number of programs  ? Can you please help me with that

Comment: You closed off access to `/usr` so you can try to put `chmod` in your home directory and run that, instead. *If* you had another EC2 instance, for example, you can take its copy of the `chmod` program at `/usr/bin/chmod`, and put it on the system that is giving you problems (i.e., ftp it over).  Then, use this `chmod` command to fix `/usr`.  If you don't have this option available to you, then you are stuck...

Comment: @Community what part is unclear ? I have mentioned above that accidently I changed /usr/ permission to "Read" only and now I am unable to perform any operation on the server. What can I do to reset the permission or get the earlier permission , so that I can perform normal commands again like : "vi" , "clear" , "sudo" , "chmod"

Comment: @matigo nope. same method is possible ;-)

Answer (score 0):

When you are using instances (google cloud, aws, azure) the method to do this is:

Create a new instance, attach the old instance as a mountpoint, fix your settings on the mount point, and boot into your old instance.

Comment: Hey @Rinzwind , thanks for you answer , can you please help me with some steps . Didn't understand.

Comment: That is going to a very long read and I know how to do it in google gce AWS seems similar and AWS has a guide here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EC2_GetStarted.html But you probably know most of that since you already have an instance(?)